# Netlogo Api Controller - Get Table View

Tags: java, api, spring-boot, controller, netlogo

I am using Netlogo Api Controller With spring boot
this my code (i got it from this [link](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/Controlling-API) )

```
HeadlessWorkspace workspace = HeadlessWorkspace.newInstance();
        try {
             workspace.open("models/Residential_Solar_PV_Adoption.nlogo",true);

             workspace.command("set number-of-residences 900");
             workspace.command("set %-similar-wanted 7");
             workspace.command("set count-years-simulated 14");
             workspace.command("set number-of-residences 500");
             workspace.command("set carbon-tax 13.7");
             workspace.command("setup");
             workspace.command("repeat 10 [ go ]");
             workspace.command("reset-ticks");
             workspace.dispose();

             workspace.dispose();
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
                  ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

i got this result in the console:

[image]

But I want to get the table view and save to database. Which command can I use to get the table view ?

Table view:

[image]

any help please ?

Comment: The "table view" that you are showing is the result of running a BehaviorSpace experiment. Unless you're trying to do something unusual, this is not something you would use the controlling API to produce: just use BehaviorSpace directly instead. And if you *are* trying to do something unusual, it might be worth explaining what it is in your question so we can better help you...

Comment: @NicolasPayette yes i have to use BehaviorSpace directly . any link to help ? i want to get result on a web application .thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can clarify why you're trying to generate the data this way, I or others might be able to give better advice.

There is no single NetLogo command or NetLogo API method to generate that table, you have to use BehaviorSpace to get it.  Here are some options, listed in rough order of simplest to hardest.

**Option 1**

If possible, I'd recommend just running BehaviorSpace experiments from the command line to generate your table.  This will get you exactly the same output you're looking for.  You can find information on how to do that in [the NetLogo manual's BehaviorSpace guide](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/behaviorspace.html#running-from-the-command-line).  If necessary, you can run NetLogo headless from the command line from within a Java program, just look for resources on calling out to external programs from Java, maybe with `ProcessBuilder`.

If you're running from within Java in order to setup and change the parameters of your BehaviorSpace experiments in a way that you cannot do from within the program, you could instead generate experiment XML files in Java to pass to NetLogo at the command line.  See [the docs on the XML format](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/behaviorspace.html#setting-up-experiments-in-xml).

**Option 2**

You can recreate the contents of the table using the CSV extension in your model and adding a few more commands to generate the data.  This will not create the exact same table, but it will get your data output in a computer and human readable format.

In pure NetLogo code, you'd want something like the below.  Note that you can control more of the behavior (like file names or the desired variables) by running other pre-experiment commands before running `setup` or `go` in your Java code.  You could also run the CSV-specific file code from Java using the controlling API and leave the model unchanged, but you'll need to write your own NetLogo code version of the `csv:to-row` primitive.

```
globals [
  ;; your model globals here

  output-variables
]

to setup
  clear-all

  ;;; your model setup code here

  file-open "my-output.csv"
  ; the given variables should be valid reporters for the NetLogo model
  set output-variables [ "ticks" "current-price" "number-of-residences" "count-years-simulated" "solar-PV-cost" "%-lows" "k" ]
  file-print csv:to-row output-variables

  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ;;; the rest of your model code here

  file-print csv:to-row map [ v -> runresult v ] output-variables
  file-flush
  tick
end
```

**Option 3**

If you really need to reproduce the BehaviorSpace table export exactly, you can try to run a BehaviorSpace experiment directly from Java.  The table is generated [by this code](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/blob/hexy/netlogo-core/src/main/lab/TableExporter.scala) but as you can see it's tied in with the `LabProtocol` class, meaning you'll have to setup and run your model through BehaviorSpace instead of just step-by-step using a workspace as you've done in your sample code.

A good example of this might be [the `Main.scala` object](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/blob/hexy/netlogo-gui/src/main/headless/Main.scala#L15-L34), which extracts some experiment settings from the expected command-line arguments, and then uses them with the `lab.run()` method to run the BehaviorSpace experiment and generate the output.  That's Scala code and not Java, but hopefully it isn't too hard to translate.  You'd similarly have to setup an `org.nlogo.nvm.LabInterface.Settings` instance and pass that off to a `HeadlessWorkspace.newLab.run()` to get things going.